# Problema para atribuir mais de um valor para variável

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int d;
int e;
int peca1;  


printf("digite um lado da peca: ");
scanf("%i", &d);
printf("digite outro lado da peca: ");
scanf("%i", &e);

peca1 = d , e 
printf("%i, %i", peca1);

return 0;

}
```

Queria atribuir o valor de `d` e `e` para que seja o valor de peca1, no entanto não consigo.

Devo usar ponteiros para atribuir esses 2 valores para `peca1`?

Comment: Sua variável é to tipo Int, não tem como você guardar dois valores diferentes nessa variável.

Comment: no caso a pesa teria uma dimensão ao invés de apenas um valor?

Comment: você poderia colocar a mesma como string e concatenar as duas

Comment: Ou então guardar os 2 valores num array e depois exibi-los.

Comment: Consegui por array. Obrigado pela ajuda galera!

Comment: @BrunoCosta A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando aceitar terá os 15 pontos necessários).

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível armazenar dois valores na mesma variável de um tipo escalar como é o caso de inteiros. Nem parece ter qualquer utilidade fazer isto neste código. Claro, sei que pode ser um exercício que exija justamente isto. Se é o caso, deveria deixar isto explícito.

Nem vou falar dos erros de sintaxe. Sem o erro o código até funcionaria se tivesse uma outra expressão, o operador de vírgula serve para separar expressões e no caso a última expressão, no caso o valor de `e`, seria o resultado final.

Se o objetivo na verdade nem era esse e sim fazer um cálculo com as duas variáveis, então faça o cálculo.

Se a intenção realmente era armazenar dois valores em uma mesma variável, isto teria que ser feito com um tipo composto. Poderia ser um ponteiro para uma lista com os dois valores, mas duvido que seja a intenção. Poderia ser um *array* que permite colocar um série de dados que funciona de forma análogo ao *array* (ainda que de forma ligeiramente diferente). Estou colocando no exemplo por causa do comentário indicando que é isto.

Pela exposição do código parece ser mais um caso de usar uma estrutura, já que não é uma sequência de dados, mas sim um conjunto específico de dados, afinal é um lado e outro lado, tem especificidade, os dados são membros de um conjunto e não elementos de uma sequência. Esta diferença semântica é importante.

De qualquer forma sem um enunciado claro, o objetivo fica ambíguo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct peca {
    int lado1;
    int lado2;
} peca;
int main() {
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    printf("digite um lado da peca: ");
    scanf("%i", &d);
    printf("digite outro lado da peca: ");
    scanf("%i", &e);
    peca peca1 = { d, e };
    printf("\n%i, %i", peca1.lado1, peca1.lado2);
    int peca[] = { d, e };
    printf("\n%i, %i", peca[0], peca[1]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/suMXN5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tjcssteo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MultipleVariables.c).